Let $I(n)=∫\tan^n xdx$, where $n>1$. Given that $I_{2024} ​ +I_{2026} ​ =a\tan^{2025} x+bx^{2025} +c$, determine the ordered pair $(a,b)$.
$I(n)=∫\tan^n xdx$, where $n>1$. Given that $I_{2024 }​ +I_{2026} ​ =a\tan^{2025} x+bx^{2025} +c$, determine the ordered pair $(a,b)$
Attempt:
I've tried using the reduction formula for ∫tan
n
xdx but haven't been able to simplify the expression to the desired form. I'm unsure how to handle the addition of $I_{2024}$ and $I_{2026}$
​
to obtain the given expression.
Question:
What is the correct approach to solving this problem? Any hints or steps would be greatly appreciated.

It would be better if you use latex to type your question.

And also how do you simplify actually? Can you show your working out? This will help us to answer your question.

Sorry bro, I am new to this platform.

Repeatedly applying the reduction formula for tan^n(x) might eventually lead to a pattern or simplification, but this is likely to be extremely tedious for such high powers. Ya so I wasn't actually able to solve it

\begin{align}\int (\tan^{2024}x+\tan^{2026}x)dx&=\int \tan^{2024}x(1+\tan^2x)dx\\&=\int\tan^{2024}xd\tan x\\&=\frac{1}{2025} \tan^{2025}x+C\end{align}

Your approach to the problem was spot on. Thanks for the assistance!
